# Query string need to be redirected using .Htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a serious issue in `.htaccess`, I have a URL like:

```
http://www.abc.com/xyz.php?title=Video-Tutoring
```

I need the URL to look like this:

```
http://www.abc.com/Video-Tutoring
```

This should affect only the page xyz.php.

Comment: Where is your tried code?

Comment: i was buzzing around like this way

Comment: [Welcome to SO, don't forget to **take the SO Tour** it will guide you on how to best use SO](http://stackoverflow.com/about)

Answer (score 0):

To *internally-redirect* http://www.abc.com/**Video-Tutoring** to http://www.abc.com/**xyz.php?title=Video-Tutoring** use this:

```
RewriteRule ^/?Video-Tutoring$ xyz.php?title=Video-Tutoring [L,QSA]
```

---

To *internally-redirect* http://www.abc.com/**ANYTHING** to http://www.abc.com/**xyz.php?title=ANYTHING** use this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ xyz.php?title=$1 [L,QSA]
```

---

To redirect the *URL visible by the user* from http://www.abc.com/**Video-Tutoring** to http://www.abc.com/**xyz.php?title=Video-Tutoring** use this:

```
RewriteRule ^/?Video-Tutoring$ xyz.php?title=Video-Tutoring [R=301,L]
```

---

To redirect the *URL visible by the user* from http://www.abc.com/**ANYTHING** to http://www.abc.com/**xyz.php?title=ANYTHING** use this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ xyz.php?title=$1 [R=301,L]
```

---

To redirect the *URL visible by the user* from http://www.abc.com/**xyz.php?title=Video-Tutoring** to http://www.abc.com/**Video-Tutoring** use this:

```
RewriteRule ^/?xyz\.php\?title=Video-Tutoring$ Video-Tutoring [R=301,L]
```

---

To redirect the *URL visible by the user* from http://www.abc.com/**xyz.php?title=ANYTHING** to http://www.abc.com/**ANYTHING** use this:

```
RewriteRule ^/?xyz\.php\?title=(.*)$ $1 [R=301,L]
```

---

I hope that helps!
By the way the above is to put in your `.htaccess` file after the line `RewriteEngine On`

Comment: I think i need exactly opposite of this solution, query string to User Friendly url.

Comment: @DhrubajyotiMondal I just edited my answer to add this case scenario ;) Cheers

Comment: For video-Tutoring it is working, but i need to know how do i make it dynamic?

Comment: @DhrubajyotiMondal see the last example with "ANYTHING", it works with anything... this is dynamic ;)

Comment: @DhrubajyotiMondal please accept the answer if that works, otherwise please clarify your question. Cheers

Comment: @DhrubajyotiMondal awesome! then would you mind accepting the answer by clicking the "V" on its left? Thanks!